# Error al utilizar get_browser desde Laravel 5.7?

Tags: php

tengo un proyecto que realizar en Laravel 5.7, he estado intentando obtener el navegador y el sistema operativo con la función get_browser de php, sin embargo me lanza este error.

```
get_browser(): browscap ini directive not set (View: 
C:\xampp\htdocs\procesofoto\resources\views\datos.blade.php)
```

Mi código en la vista es:

```
 <?php
            $navegador = get_browser(null,true);
            print_r($navegador);
  ?>
```

En el archivo php.ini solo modifique esta línea

```
[browscap]
; http://php.net/browscap
browscap="C:\xampp\php\extras\browscap.ini"
```

y tengo mi archivo justamente en esa dirección, ademas de que tome el ultimo archivo que se actualizo desde la pagina de php. En un inicio si me lanzaba resultados pero después de varias recargas a la pagina comenzó a lanzarme ese error. ¿Como puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: Por la ruta que especificas supongo que estás usando `Apache`, ¿intentaste reiniciar `Apache` después de hacer el cambio a tu archivo `php.ini`?

Comment: puedes hacer un `$request->header('User-Agent');` que es lo mismo!

Comment: @Bryro intente hacer eso, sin embargo lo unico que arroja es:            Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36.                                                  y lo que estoy buscando obtener es realmente cual es el navegador en el que esta el usuario y el sistema, el cual no corresponde.

Comment: @AarónGutiérrez si, asi es estoy utilizando xampp y si lo reinicie, pero el resultado es el mismo.

Comment: @AndreaEscobar ¿Estás segura que tu proyecto está jalando el archivo `php.ini` que estás modificando?, para verificar ejecuta `phpinfo()` desde cualquier parte del proyecto, después localiza la parte que dice "loaded ini file" o algo parecido en lo que te devuelve la función, normalmente está casi al principio, checa si la ruta del archivo `php.ini` cargado coincide con la del archivo que modificaste...

Comment: @AndreaEscobar Si no logras activar la extensión prueba usando la siguiente librería: https://github.com/jenssegers/agent

Comment: @AarónGutiérrez no logre activar la extensión, pero si me funciono la librería, muchas gracias.